# After validation return false document on click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have following validation in my web page,

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.click_button', function() {
    if(($('#first_name').val() == "")){
        alert('Firstname missing');
        return false;
    }
    // post to ajax 
});
```

Once it met with firstname missing validation error the click event (for class `click_button`) will not work afterward. How can I append the click event after return false. Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: A jQuery object will never equate to an empty string, so your `if` condition is flawed. Do you mean `$('#first_name').val()` instead?

Comment: It's not clear why you want to apply click event after `return false`, any way try to use setTimeout before the return, it'll return and after the timeout finishes it'll do what ever you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
function checkFormIsValid(){
  var isValid = true;
  var input = $.trim($('#first_name').val());
  if(typeof input != 'string' || input==''){
        isValid = false;
  }
  return isValid;
}

$( document ).on( 'click', '.click_button', function(e) {
  if(checkFormIsValid()){
    //do your stuff
  }else{
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('Firstname missing');
     return false;
  }
});
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/adwp6dLe/2/

Answer (score 0):

please review this one (basically i don't add anything. only $('#first_name').val() === "" ). your code's working

html

```
<input id="first_name">
<button type="button" class="click_button">post</button>
```

javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.click_button', function(e) {
  if (($('#first_name').val() === "")) {
    alert('Firstname missing');
    return false;
  }
  alert('sending');
  // post to ajax 
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rizkidwip/4wpf9tb3/1/)